# How to disable selected options with jQuery in multiple XML-fed, dynamically generated select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, forms, drop-down-menu

Ok, I've looked all around, both here and on the web, and can't begin to find an answer that fits this scenario.

I have a page that allows for dynamic creation of 5 select lists that are XML-fed. I need to disable any selected options in all of the select lists. I am confined to using jQuery 1.5.1 and have to support cross-browser back to IE7. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<fieldset class="clearfix clonedInput" id="input1">
<div class="toolTipHolder">
<label for="FooName" class="foo-select">Foo Select List
<select class="foo1 required infoTrigger foo-select" id="foo1" attr-info="This     will be tooltip text.">
<option>loading</option>
</select>
</label>
<input type="button" value="Remove this option" class="foo-remove hidden clearfix" />
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div><a href="#" class="addFoo"><input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add another foo" class="btnAdd" /></a></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//XML IMPORT CODE
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "../../includes/foo.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
var select = $('.foo1');
$(xml).find('rid').each(function(){
var fna = $(this).find('fna').text();
select.append("<option>"+fna+"</option>");
$(this).find('value').each(function(){
var value = $(this).text();
});
});
select.children(":first").text("please make a selection").attr("selected",true);
$("input, select").focus(function(){ $(this).fooTooltip(); });
}
});
// CODE TO ADD/REMOVE ELEMENTS
$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
var num     = $('fieldset.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields
var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field
var selects = $('select');      //for all select lists
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
newElem.children().find('select.foo-select').attr('id', 'foo' + newNum);
newElem.find('input.foo-remove').removeClass('hidden').attr('disabled','').attr('id', 'foo' + newNum);
$('#input' + num).after(newElem);
$("input, select").focus(function(){ $(this).fooTooltip(); });
$("select[id^='foo'] option:selected").val();
$('option[value="value-to-search-for"]', this).remove();
selects.change(function() {
var vals = {};
selects.each(function() { 
vals[this.value] = true; }).get();
selects.not(this).children().not(':selected').not(':first-child').each(function() { this.disabled = vals[this.value]; });
});
if (newNum == 5)
$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
return false;
});
$('input.foo-remove').live("click", function() {
$(this).closest('fieldset.clonedInput').remove();
var num = $('fieldset.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields
$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
if (num-1 == 0)
$('.foo-remove').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('hidden');
return false;
});
});
```

The disabling of selected options will work when adding the first cloned select list, but will not work on on subsequent clones.  I've thrown everything at this and just can't get it.  Please...any help is incredibly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, say your variable `fna` is "foo":

```
select.append("<option class="+fna+">"+fna+"</option>");
```

Then add a click handler that like this:

```
$("option").live("click",function(){
    var _class = $(this).attr("class");
    $("."+class).hide();
});
```

So, on an option with class (and value) of "foo", you hide all other "foo" options whenever one of them is clicked.

So crazy it just may work. . .;).

Good luck!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying to add a new, free-standing click handler function or to add this to one of the pre-existing?

Comment: Hey Jen-I didn't see your original handler in there (in a hurry) but just add this one as well at first and see where it gets you.  You actually need the "live" part since you are adding elements to the DOM dynamically.  If that works, then yeah, you probably want to roll your existing click logic in with it.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. It's a very interesting idea that I hadn't considered - I'll give it try. Another question, though...what if a user adds a select list, selects an option in that select list (adding the disable class to that option in all other lists), but then removes the select list with the option selected? In my code when this happened the disabled state was left on the corresponding option in the other select lists on the page.